# android connection to php for sending login verification code to mobile

Tags: php, android, json

I am developing an android app for a website.In website for login, every time after checking the username and password a verification code is send to user for filling next part of login page.In android app with same functionalities I am able to check the username and password.But I am not sure about if it is possible to trigger the php code for sending verification code to mobile.Please tell me it is possible or not.I am using Httppost in android with json parsing.

sndactivation_code.php

```
<?php
set_include_path("/home2/tradeni1/php");
require_once("HTTP/Request2.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['user_id']))
{
$id=$_SESSION['uid'];
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO code (`id` ,`code` ,`user_id` ,`status`) VALUES ('' , '', '$id','0')");
$lastid=mysql_insert_id();
$code=rand(100000,999999);//"stock_".$lastid;
$_SESSION['code']=$code;
$sql1=mysql_query("UPDATE code SET code = '$code' WHERE id='$lastid'");


$user_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($user_res) == 0) {
    $user_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribers where id='$id'");
}

$user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_res);

$username = ucfirst($user_row['name']);
$phone = $user_row['mobile'];
$date = date("d M Y",time());
}

$message = "Dear " . $username . ", your one time login code for " . $date . " is " . $code;
$data = array(
    'username' => 'trdnif',
    'password' => 'trade123',
    'from' => 'TRDNIF',
    'to' => $phone,
    'udh' => "",
    'dlr-mask' => 19,
    'dlr-url' => "",
    'text' => $message
);

$request = new HTTP_Request2("http://myvaluefirst.com/smpp/sendsms", HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
$url = $request->getUrl();
$url->setQueryVariables($data);
try {
    $response = $request->send();
    if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
        //echo $response->getBody();
    } else {
        //echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' . $response->getReasonPhrase();
        echo "";
    }
} catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
    //echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an endpoint on the server side which both the website and the app can post the username and password to and in response they get the access code.